# How to run 32-bit matlab on 64-bit linux machine?

Tags: linux, matlab

When I run this code in 64-bit Matlab, it displays 'This function can run only with MS Windows or Linux'.

```
 % Call the binary executable
fpath = fileparts(which(mfilename));
if strncmp(computer,'PC',2) % MS Windows
  exec_str = ['"' fpath '/xcv_segment.exe"'];
elseif strcmp(computer,'GLNX86') % Linux
  exec_str = [fpath '/xcv_segment'];
else error('This function can run only with MS Windows or Linux');
end
```

For this reason, I tried to install lib-32 in order to install glnx86.

```
 sudo -i
    cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
    echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
    apt-get update
    apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Then, I run this command to install 32-bit matlab: `./install -glnx86`
After this installing, I run the same code. However, it keeps going on the same message:`'This function can run only with MS Windows or Linux'.`

Answer (score 0):

The `computer` function checks what operating system you're running on. It's not an error related to the external binary (which isn't even being called at this point in the code), or the version of Matlab.  It's the `if/elseif` segment stopping you going any further.

Run `computer` at the command line and you'll see the output has nothing to do with Matlab version.

You can change that code to accept 64 bit linux by changing the `elseif` to accept glxna64, whether it then runs the external binary is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

for 64 bits linux machines the matlab command `computer` returns the string 'GLNXA64', and you tried to compare with 'GLNX86'.

Your error is not related to not being able to run 32 bit binary in a 64 bit matlab, because your code does not reach the point that tries to do so. (the ifs take you to the error)

Comment: However, I tried to run only  `fpath = fileparts(which(mfilename));                   exec_str = [fpath '/xcv_segment']; ` It says `Permission Denied`.

Answer (score -3):

Use a program like WINE. WINE helps windows executables and dll libraries to work on linux.